# changing the position of headings

Tags: r

I am trying to draw pie charts using R with the following code. The headings are far from the pie charts. I would like to get the pie charts just below the headings. How can I do that?

```
x <-  c(632,20,491,991,20)
y <- c(37376,41770,5210,5005,3947)
names <- c("alpha","beta","gamma","delta","omega")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
pie(x, names, col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "cyan"), main="PIE CHART 1")
pie(y, names,col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "cyan"),  main="PIE CHART 2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <-  c(632,20,491,991,20)
y <- c(37376,41770,5210,5005,3947)
names <- c("alpha","beta","gamma","delta","omega")
par(fig=c(0,0.5,0,1))
pie(x, names, col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "cyan"))
title("CHART 1", line=-3)
par(fig=c(0.5,1,0,1),new=TRUE)
pie(y, names,col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "cyan"))
title("CHART 2", line=-3)
```

Alterations:

- Par - change control to fig=c(x,x,y,y) to specify that you want each plot to take up a portion of the window so as it is at the moment I have got each pie chart taking up half of the plot window
- Par new=TRUE states that you want a second plot "overlaid"
- Title - separate from plot, line=x states where you want the title to sit, play around with various - figures until you get what you want

---

As an alternative, you can also keep using `mfrow`:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
pie(x, names, col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "cyan"))
title("PIE CHART 1", line=-1)
pie(y, names, col = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "cyan"))
title("PIE CHART 2", line=-1)
```

Comment: No probs - you might be able to do it with mfrow too (never tried), but personally I find fig more useful as it allows you to proportion plots more precisely than effectively splitting the plot window into smaller equal-sized squares